# Convert ruby array to string

Tags: ruby, arrays

I'm fairly new to ruby. I have the following csv:

```
Office (1), Test 
Office (Test)(2), Test
```

In "data.csv".

Then in my ruby script I have;

```
CSV.foreach("data.csv") do |line|
  registeredOffice = line[0].to_s() 
  macOffice = registeredOffice.scan(/\(([^\)]+)\)/).last


  csvText = "#{csvText}\n#{macOffice}"
end
```

Which gives me

```
["1"]
["2"]
```

However I want to know how to convert the above to a string so the output is

```
1
2
```

Using `.join` or `[0]` returns a `nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like:

```
macOffice = registeredOffice[/(\d+)\)$/, 1]
```

scan with capture groups will give you multi-d arrays

Answer (score 0):

The following line:

```
macOffice = registeredOffice.scan(/\(([^\)]+)\)/).last
```

returns array since scan returns array of array. For the first line of `data.csv`, it is `["1"]`.

I guess you need scalar value for `macOffice`, thus, you want to use match which only returns non-repetive match using `match`, which returns array of matches once. For example, you can grab first match from the returned array using `[1]` subscript, thus:

```
macOffice = registeredOffice.match(/\(([^\)]+)\)/)[1]
```

which returns `1`.

Assuming you want an array you can write like this:

```
out = []
CSV.foreach("data.csv") do |line|
  registeredOffice = line[0].to_s() 
  macOffice = registeredOffice.match(/\((\d+)\)/)[1]
  out.push(macOffice)
end

puts out.join(",")
```

to produce `1,2`